# toggle Span class with button in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

So I'm playing around with Font Awesome and BootStrap, and I'm looking for a way to toggle my star icon on the button. Problem is, it's inside a loop.

```
{% for i in X %}
    <button id="{{i.id}}"><span class="class1" id="StarIcon"></span></button>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to change the respective span from 'class1' to 'class2' upon click, however just knowing how to change all of them or even just the last one would already be of help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()`:

```js
const el = document.getElementById('someButton');

document.getElementById('{{i.id}}').onclick = () => {
  el.classList.add('class2');
  el.classList.remove('class1')
}
```

```html
<button id="{{i.id}}"><i id="someButton" class="class1" id="StarIcon">Button!</i></button>
```

Comment: Nope, nothing happened. Also, there's another problem with this: I only want the respective 'i' to change classes, not all of them. I updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: you may want to assign your `i` and `id`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understtod you right, but probably you're looking for something like this:

```
{% for i in X %}
    <button id="{{i.id}}"><span class="class1" id="StarIcon"  onclick="btnClick(this)"></span></button>
{% endfor %}
```

...

```
function btnClick(el) {
    const spanEl = el.querySelector('#StarIcon');
    if (spanEl.classList.contains('class1')) {
        setClass2(spanEl);
    } else if (spanEl.classList.contains('class2')) {
        setClass1(spanEl);
    }
}
function setClass1(el) {
    el.classList.add('class1');
    el.classList.remove('class2');
}
function setClass2(el) {
    el.classList.add('class2');
    el.classList.remove('class1');
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. To make it clearer: I'm generating columns with buttons in that %for%. Inside my buttons I have <i class="far fa-star"> which is a Star Icon in Font Awesome. I want to change that Icon by changing the Font Awesome Class when I click a button. All buttons have different IDs defined by {{i.id}}